# ghci in terminal only shows version and can't load program into ghc

Tags: macos, haskell, emacs, textwrangler

The first problem is when I write ghci in the terminal (I use an Apple Mac), it only shows the version, it seems it's not loading anything. In my case, like following:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
```

And nothing, I checked YouTube for some instructions, most like this:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCc2U.png)

After the first line, floor 3 lines indicating loading.

The second problem is when I write some basic calculations it works fine in terminal, I just need to write ghci go to the mode. But I can not load files into ghci. I change the extension to .hs and then i write :load . I tried emacs and TextWrangler but both don't work. The problem is like this:

```
$ :load program
-bash: :load: command not found
```

I need some help because now I am very confused.

Comment: Why are you writing `:quit`? That'll quit `ghci` and put you back in `bash`.

Comment: you could also run `ghci program.hs` instead of `:load`

Comment: @Rorschach - In ghci, try to type ":browse" and by default you should see all prelude stuff...

If I understand correctly, are you writing ":load" command in bash?

Comment: regarding the first problem,i type the lines that i don't have.See following

Comment: loading package ghc-prim … linking … done.
loading package integer-gmp … linking … done.
loading package base … linking … done.
Prelude>

Answer (score 1):

**GHCI** - It's ghc's interactive environment, which in your case you are starting from bash. It gives you interactive prompt, with its own set of commands, which you can display by commands *:?* or *:help*.

After typing *ghci* in *bash* you start ghci, which will automatically load basic haskell library called *Prelude*, which ghci prints in its prompt.

```
$ ghci                  # Run ghci

[Prelude> :?            -- show me some help
[Prelude> :browse       -- show all loaded stuff
[Prelude> :load program -- compile and load 'program.hs' into ghci
[Prelude> sqrt(2+6)     -- I can do here all haskell stuff too
[Prelude> :quit         -- Leave back to bash

$ ghci program.hs       # Start and load 'program.hs' into ghci
$ :load                 # Ooops this won't work, it's not a BASH command, it's GHCI command
```

*Note:* Sign '#' is a bash comment and '--' is haskell comment.

Comment: I have i file called set.hs and another program.hs.In ghci i can not load these both.The case is following

Comment: fruitdeMacBook-Pro:~ fruit$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :l program
target ‘program’ is not a module name or a source file
Prelude> :l set
target ‘set’ is not a module name or a source file

Comment: That's because of paths... Either you will specify full path to source file or relative. Best would be to run ghci in directory where you have your *.hs files.

Comment: What is that mean?